# What is a real world example of using a unit struct?

Tags: struct, rust

I read [these](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.struct.html) docs about structs, but I don't understand about unit structs. It says:

> Unit structs are most commonly used as marker. They have a size of zero bytes, but unlike empty enums they can be instantiated, making them isomorphic to the unit type `()`. Unit structs are useful when you need to implement a trait on something, but don’t need to store any data inside it.

they only give this piece of code as an example:

```rust
struct Unit;
```

What is a real world example of using a unit struct?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Standard library

### `Global`

The global memory allocator, [`Global`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Global.html), is a unit struct:

```rust
pub struct Global;
```

It has no state of its own (because the state is global), but it implements traits like [`Allocator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/trait.Allocator.html).

### `std::fmt::Error`

The error for string formatting, [`std::fmt::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Error.html), is a unit struct:

```rust
pub struct Error;
```

It has no state of its own, but it implements traits like [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html).

### `RangeFull`

The type for the `..` operator, [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html), is a unit struct:

```rust
pub struct RangeFull;
```

It has no state of its own, but it implements traits like [`RangeBounds`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.RangeBounds.html).

## Crates

### `chrono::Utc`

The [`Utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html) timezone is a unit struct:

```rust
pub struct Utc;
```

It has no state of its own, but it implements traits like [`TimeZone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html#impl-TimeZone) and is thus usable as a generic argument to `Date` and `DateTime`.

Comment: [`Utc`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.19/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html) timezone from the chrono trait - a unit struct, no state of its own, but implements the `TimeZone` trait and hence usable as generric argument to `Date` and `DateTime`.

Comment: @Shepmaster sorry you're right I confused zero-sized types with unit structs. On a relevant note, `std::alloc::AllocError`, `std::sync::mpsc::RecvError`, and `std::option::NoneError` are all unit structs, although two of those are only on nightly.

Comment: @Aiden4 yeah, after grepping the standard library for unit structs, I had to filter it down a bit; I tried to grab ones that were stable and that were more likely to have been encountered.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to providing a basis for stateless trait implementations, you may also see unit structs created simply to serve as a *marker* (as mentioned in the quote) to be used in some other structure. Some examples:

- In [`std::marker`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/index.html), there are `PhantomData` and `PhantomPinned` which are used to augment other types in concert with the compiler for variance, auto-generated traits, or other behavior. These in particular are special cases and not really a usable pattern outside the standard library.
- You can see marker types used in the [typestate pattern](https://willcrichton.net/rust-api-type-patterns/typestate.html). Like [`Rocket<P>`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Compact.html) in Rocket v0.5. It uses `P` as simply an indicator of what "pahse" the application is in and provides methods only with specific phases (like can't configure after it is started). *Technically `Build`/`Ingite`/`Orbit` are empty structs and not unit structs, but that distinction isn't meaningful here*.
- You can also see marker types used similarly for defining [`Format`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Format.html) options in the tracing-subscriber crate. The [`Compact`](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Compact.html) type (a unit struct) is used in conjunction with it to provide different methods and behavior that are not tied to itself directly (`Compact` implements no traits, and has no methods; the specialization comes from `Format<Compact, T>` [implementing](https://docs.rs/tracing-subscriber/latest/tracing_subscriber/fmt/format/struct.Format.html#impl-FormatEvent%3CS%2C%20N%3E-for-Format%3CCompact%2C%20T%3E) `FormatEvent`).